# In ColdFusion does FileRead close the file it opens?

Tags: coldfusion

If I call `fileRead` with a path argument (rather than with a file object I explicitly opened with `fileOpen`), does ColdFusion close the file it opens? Is this documented anywhere? I don't see anything about this type of behavioral guarantee on either Adobe's or CFDocs' pages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the file commands are self contained procedures that open, act on a file and then close. This is the standard expectation for any standalone command.

Comment: I agree this is the behavior one would expect, but I can't find it documented anywhere, and so it's a bit unnerving to rely on—I don't want an arbitrary number of file handles just hanging out and wasting resources. I'll keep hunting for the docs!

Comment: @DavidRogers You can file a bug report, ping the CF product guys on CFML Slack or just walk up to one of the CF devs at CF Summit next week and ask them to update the docs.

Comment: @DavidRogers While you're at it, ask them to open source the product too. :P

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno isn't that called "Lucee" ?

Comment: @DavidRogers - The omission is probably a carry over from the very, very early days of CF. Historically, it was designed to simplify common tasks like file access, querying database, etc. Most tags and functions never even exposed low level objects like handles. So it was implicit that file functions would automatically close the underlying file handles. (Like it's just "understood" that you don't have to manually close database connections when using query tags/functions). Once CF8 exposed file handles to developers, Adobe probably should've updated the documentation, but  never did.

Comment: Good point about queries, I never considered worrying about resource leaks there. Now I will! :)

Comment: If I was concerned with resource leaks, I would put the `fileRead()` in a function and make sure to `local.` or `var` scope any associated variables.

Comment: @DavidRogers - LOL. You can easily verify yourself that CF closes file handles and database connections (though if you're using connection pooling CF obviously maintains a pool of *open* connections for performance).  Are you just interested in how things work under the hood or is there a specific reason you're worried about resource leaks?

Comment: I've never encountered any issues with `fileRead` in the last 7 years. Just don't use it on huge files as it will buffer the file content in memory. That's what streaming with `fileOpen` is for. And that one requires you to use try/catch/finally with `fileClose`.